# UserForm. Ошибка при при суммирование чисел из TextBox

Tags: vba, форма

Здравствуйте!
Столкнулся с странным багом в VBA при сложении двух двузначных чисел (только от 10 до 19 включительно).
Есть форма в которой пользователю предлагается указать N-ое количество людей для разных кабинетов:
[image: Программа складывает все значения полей и выводит сумму в поле "Всего"]

Если складывать числа от 1 до 9 или от 20 и выше, то все работает как надо.
Но, если мы укажем в любом поле порядковые числа идущие друг за другом, то в поле "Всего" будет отображаться не сумма значений, а последнее слагаемое (как в приведенном скриншоте).
При чем если в поле "Всего" (оно не редактируемое) выделить результат и нажать Delete на клавиатуре, то поле отобразит верный результат (как будто просто в память записалось последнее слагаемое, а мы, нажав на кнопку почистили кэш и все ОК). 
Если мы сложим к примеру числа 12 и 14, то все ок. 
Или если напишем наоборот 13 и 12, то тоже все правильно отображается.
Но вот когда мы хотим подсчитать числа идущие друг за другом в промежутке от 10 до 19 (Если ТОЛЬКО два числа, три и больше значений считает хорошо), то вот такой странный глюк получается. Помогите разобраться в чем дело.

Код логики работы формы:

```
Private Sub TB_311_Change()

If TB_Total.Value <> "" Then
    If TB_311.Value = "" Then
        TB_Total.Value = ""
    Else
        TB_Total.Value = CInt(TB_311.Value)
    End If
Else
    If TB_311.Value = "" Then
        TB_Total.Value = ""
    Else
        TB_Total.Value = CInt(TB_311.Value)
    End If
End If
End Sub

Private Sub TB_314_Change()

    If TB_Total.Value <> "" Then
       If TB_314.Value = "" Then
            TB_Total.Value = ""
       Else
            TB_Total.Value = CInt(TB_314.Value)
    End If
    Else
        If TB_314.Value = "" Then
            TB_Total.Value = ""
        Else
            TB_Total.Value = CInt(TB_314.Value)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
' КОНЕЦ

' Итоговое количество слушателей в кабинетах
Private Sub TB_Total_Change()

    Dim int301 As Integer
    Dim int208 As Integer
    Dim int202 As Integer
    Dim int203 As Integer
    Dim int205 As Integer
    Dim int206 As Integer
    Dim int207 As Integer
    Dim int311 As Integer
    Dim int314 As Integer

    ' Если поле не имеет значения, тогда присваиваем ему ноль
    If TB_301.Value = "" Then
        int301 = 0
    Else
        int301 = TB_301.Value
    End If

    If TB_208.Value = "" Then
        int208 = 0
    Else
        int208 = TB_208.Value
    End If

    If TB_202.Value = "" Then
        int202 = 0
    Else
        int202 = TB_202.Value
    End If

    If TB_203.Value = "" Then
        int203 = 0
    Else
        int203 = TB_203.Value
    End If

    If TB_205.Value = "" Then
        int205 = 0
    Else
        int205 = TB_205.Value
    End If

    If TB_206.Value = "" Then
        int206 = 0
    Else
        int206 = TB_206.Value
    End If

    If TB_207.Value = "" Then
        int207 = 0
    Else
        int207 = TB_207.Value
    End If

    If TB_311.Value = "" Then
        int311 = 0
    Else
        int311 = TB_311.Value
    End If

    If TB_314.Value = "" Then
        int314 = 0
    Else
        int314 = TB_314.Value
    End If

    TB_Total.Value = int301 + int208 + int202 + int203 + int205 + int206 + int207 + int311 + int314
End Sub
```

Comment: Без кода - гадание на кофейной гуще...

Comment: Еще раз повторю, что сложение любых других чисел в любом порядке работает отлично, но вот если порядковые от 10 до 19 - прямо беда.

Comment: Кажется догадался. Нужно указать еще одно условие для проверки. Как сделаю напишу.

Answer (score 1):

Переписал условия при изменении значения полей и все заработало как надо:

```
Private Sub TB_314_Change()
    If TB_314.Value = "" Then
        TB_Total.Value = ""
    Else
        If TB_314.Value = TB_Total.Value Then
            TB_Total.Value = ""
        Else
            TB_Total.Value = CInt(TB_314.Value)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Достаточно было добавить условие `If TB_314.Value = TB_Total.Value Then` и если есть совпадение (количество в кабинете совпадает с количеством всего), то написать пустую строчку в "Всего", не внося никаких изменений.

Answer (score 0):

Обработка события изменения в *TextBox*. В таком варианте любое нечисловое значение преобразуется в ноль, в числовом дробном останется только целое:

```
Private Sub TB_311_Change()
    TB_311.Text = Val(TB_311.Text)
    Call CountTotal ' к суммированию'
End Sub
```

Суммирование в *TB_Total*:

```
Private Sub CountTotal() 
Dim lSum As Long
Dim x As Control
    For Each x In Me.Controls ' проходим по всем контролам'
        If TypeName(x) = "TextBox" Then     ' если TextBox'
            If x.Name <> "TB_Total" Then    ' и его имя не TB_Total'
                lSum = lSum + Val(x.Text)   ' суммируем'
            End If
        End If
    Next x

    TB_Total.Text = lSum ' сумма в TB_Total'
End Sub
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за идею!